# When using rexponseType Blob actual error is not coming from backed ony OK is showing in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11

[image]some code has been added service type script file. The actual error code is not coming from baked service file. How to resolve this issue in angular.

```
downloadInvoiceFile(body:any){  
  console.log("Generate Invoice file download: "+JSON.stringify(body));
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post(this.baseurl+"/dealEntry/downloadTradeInvoiceFile",body, { responseType: 'blob'})
    .pipe(
        timeout(this.apiTimeOut)
      ).subscribe((res: any) => {
        resolve(res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

some code has been added component type script file. The actual error code is not coming from baked service file. How to resolve this issue in angular.

```
downloadInvoice(){    
  this.generateInvoiceValidate();
  
  if(!this.vaidateStatus){
    return;
  }
   let datrnumberta = {
    "userId": this.loggedUserId,
    "tradeNumber": this.tradeNumber,
  };
  this.loader.loaderdiv = true;  
  this.api.downloadInvoiceFile(datrnumberta).then((res:any)=> {
    console.log("Generate Invoice"+JSON.stringify(res));    
    this.loader.loaderdiv = false;     
    try{
      const blob: any = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
      const file = new File([blob], 'InvoiceDocument_'+this.tradeNumber+'.xlsx', { type: 'application/vnd.ms.excel'});
      saveAs(file);
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'File saving failed',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        });
    }
 }).catch((err)=> {
   console.log('Error Due to Download file: ', JSON.stringify(err));
   Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: err,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        });
        this.loader.loaderdiv = false;
 });
     
 }
```

Comment: Can you add info about your error? Maybe the error message, or specify in which part the error appears.

Comment: Image has been addedresponseType : blob used so its coming